# Why is there unbound local error in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(censor_email_two(proprietary_terms))
  File "script.py", line 23, in censor_email_two
    result = ''.join(result.split(term_new[i]))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

```py
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]
def censor_email_two(term):
  email_two_new = email_two.split()
  term_new = ' '.join(str(term).split())
  for item in email_two_new: # to search EXACT wordings with a variable
    for i in range(len(term_new)):
      if item == term_new[i]: # to search EXACT wordings with a variable
        if i == 0:
          result = ''.join(email_two.split(term_new[i]))
        if i > 0 and i < len(term_new) - 1:
          result = ''.join(result.split(term_new[i]))
        if i == len(term_new) - 1:
          result = ''.join(result.split(term_new[i]))
          return result    
      else:
        continue
```

Also, are there any syntax errors among these lines of codes? `email_two` has already been defined as a global variable

Comment: Well the error is pretty much self-explanatory... you're using `result` inside `join`, when it wasn't yet defined...

Comment: You need to initialise result with some default value of course.

Comment: But I have defined it at `if i == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

you referencing result when assigning result( result inside the join method ). python doesn't know what result is inside the join method

```
result = ''.join(result.split(...)) ## error!
```

first assign result to `result = ''` at the beginning of your function

```
def censor_email_two(term):
    result = ''
```